# Twilio: Is it possible to generate access token to connect to a video room without using SDK?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am wondering what will be the steps require to generate an access token to connect to a room as the documentation only shows this using an SDK

https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens

ANd is it possible to connect into this room also via REST API? as I cant find this in the documentation

Comment: This I believe https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api-key-resource

Comment: Can you clarify why the SDK cannot be used? The Twilio CLI has a plug-in for testing, https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/plugins.

Comment: @Alan I want to build the app within salesforce, unless is there a Salesforce SDK?